# How to Use AddressSanitizer on Android NDK GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, android-ndk, address-sanitizer

I want use AddressSanitizer  to check memory problems in Android Native C++ Code compile with GCC 4.9.

so, I set

```
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  -g1 -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer")
SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -g1 -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer")
SET (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -fsanitize=address -static-libasan")
```

in my CMakeLists.txt file.

but I got an error:

> ld.exe: error: cannot find -lasan",i find in NDK directory,i do not
>   find libasan.so

Is NDK GCC different from NDK Clang? in NDK,just Clan Support AddressSanitizer?

Comment: _"just Clang Support AddressSanitizer?"_ Yes: _"As a first step to building an ASan-instrumented binary, make sure that your code builds with Clang"_. GCC has been deprecated in the NDK for a while anyway, and was removed altogether in NDK r18.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use ASAN with GCC in the NDK. Those libraries were never shipped. ASAN is supported with Clang, and GCC is not supported *at all* in current NDKs.

> Is NDK GCC different from NDK Clang?

In the same way that non-NDK GCC is different from non-NDK Clang, yes. They're different compilers.

Comment: i get NDK GCC 4.9 source code https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/gcc/+/ndk-r16/gcc-4.9/ , there has libsanitizer source code .so,if i comple libsanitizer  by myself ,can i get a lasan.so used to support ASAN to NDK GCC?

Comment: Maybe, but why bother?